# trouble with button click on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas that allows people to draw lines an such on the canvas, trying to implement three buttons that change the color of the lines their drawing also a button to clear the canvas. First code is my html which initializes the canvas, buttons, and then calls the javascript file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Paint Canvas</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
      #container { position: relative; }
      #imageView { border: 3px solid #000; }
    --></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="300">

      </p>

      </canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
             src=".js">
    </script>

    <input type= "button" value= "Green" id= "green" onclick= "GreenRect()" />
    <input type= "button" value= "Red" id= "red" onclick= "RedRect()" />
    <input type= "button" value= "clear canvas" id= "clear" onclick= "ImgClr()" />

    <button id="howdy">Howdy!</button>

    <br>

  </body
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
//Call Window onload
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var canvas, context, tool;

        function init() {
            // Find Canvas
            canvas = document.getElementById('imageView')
            if (!canvas) {
                alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
                return;
            }

            if (!canvas.getContext) {
                alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
                return;
            }

            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (!context) {
                alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
                return;
            }

            //Instance of drawing tool
            tool = new tool_pencil();

            // Enables mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup event
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
        }

        function howdy() {
            alert("Howdy!");
        }

        //drawing tool works like a simulated drawing
        function tool_pencil() {
            var tool = this;
            this.started = false;

            /* function event that initializes when mousedown and
             starts drawing tool on mousedown*/
            this.mousedown = function(ev) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                tool.started = true;
            };

            // draws on function mousemoves and sets a specific color and width
            // to line

            this.mousemove = function(ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
                    context.stroke();
                    context.strokeStyle = '#FF4500';
                    context.lineWidth = 8;
                    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
                    context.fill();
                }
            };

            // mouseup function, stops drawing
            this.mouseup = function(ev) {
                if (tool.started) {
                    tool.mousemove(ev);
                    tool.started = false;
                }
            };
        }

        /* finds mouse position on canvas*/
        function ev_canvas(ev) {
            if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) {
                ev._x = ev.layerX;
                ev._y = ev.layerY;
            } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) {
                ev._x = ev.offsetX;
                ev._y = ev.offsetY;
            }

            var func = tool[ev.type];
            if (func) {
                func(ev);
            }
        }

        init();

    }, false);

    function GreenRect() {
        context.strokeStyle = 'green';
        context.stroke();
    }

    function RedRect() {
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
        context.stroke();
    }

    function ImgClr() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Do you have a specific problem that you need help with?

Comment: What's with the closing `p` tag in the canvas?

Comment: the buttons that change color to green and red don't work. I see them displayed below the canvas but their not changing the color of the line on the canvas like suppose to as well as clear canvas is not working either.

Comment: I reformatted the HTML and it may render, but it's malformed.  Make sure the tags match up, that they all close, etc.

Comment: When I've read your code much deeper I assume youe have problems with javascript scope. Maybe this will help you to understand it more: http://dailyjs.com/2012/07/23/js101-scope/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `context` is not reachable into `GreenRect` and `RedRect` functions scope. Try make it global definig `contex` on first line of js code.

You also should try to write more readable code - that will help you and other people to find bugs.

You also don't have script name in `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
             src=".js">
</script>
```

and have unnesessary `p` tag in your `canvas` tag:

```
<canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="300">

      </p>

</canvas>
```